# Should the server close the connection socket?

Tags: c++, linux, networking

I am using epoll to implement a socket-based server program.
When I use multithreading, some requests fail to respond. The test results using webbench are as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlYMQ.png)

```
//This is the code to listen on the socket.
//Omit the creation code of listenfd.
while (!stopserver)
{
    int num = epoll_wait(epollfd, eve, 10000, -1);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        int fd = eve[i].data.fd;
        if (fd == listenfd)
        {
            sockaddr_in caddr;
            socklen_t tmplen = sizeof(caddr);

            connfd = accept(listenfd, (sockaddr*)&caddr, &tmplen);
            assert(connfd != -1);
            //The true here is to use EPOLLONESHOT.
            addFd(epollfd, connfd, true);
        }
        else
        {
            worker.init(eve[i].data.fd, epollfd);
            threadpool->add(&worker);
        }
    }
}
```

```
bool ThreadPool::add(Worker* worker)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mutex);

    if (workerdeque.size() > maxrequestsnum)
    {
        locker.unlock();
        return false;
    }
    
    workerdeque.push_back(worker);
    locker.unlock();

    sem_post(&sem);

    return true;
}


void ThreadPool::run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        sem_wait(&sem);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mutex);

        if (workerdeque.empty())
        {
            locker.unlock();
            continue;
        }

        Worker* request = workerdeque.front();
        workerdeque.pop_front();
        locker.unlock();

        if (!request)
            continue;

        std::cout << "work: " << request->connfd << std::endl;
        request->work();
    }
}
```

```
void Worker::init(const int& connfd, const int& epollfd)
{
    this->connfd = connfd;
    this->epollfd = epollfd;
}

void Worker::work()
{
    int len = 0, totle = 0;
    char buf[4096]{ '0' };
    char temp[4096]{ '0' };

    while ((len = recv(connfd, temp, sizeof(temp), NULL)) > 0)
    {
        if (totle + len < sizeof(buf))
        {
            memcpy(buf + totle, temp, len);
            totle += len;
        }
    }
    if (len == -1 && errno == EAGAIN)
    {
        //Re-register EPOLLONESHOT event
        modfd(epollfd, connfd);
        //Parse after reading
        parser.getLine(buf, tline);
        parser.getStatus(tline, tstatus);
        parser.getFile(tline, tfile);

        std::cout << "close:" << connfd << std::endl;
        close(connfd);
    }
    else if (len == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "close" << std::endl;
        epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, connfd, NULL);
        close(connfd);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "errno:" << errno << " " << connfd << std::endl;
    }
}
```

These are the wrong output information. These are the wrong output information. It seems that they are all trying to read data from a confd (but confd should contain no data, which causes errno to be set to 9).

```
//SendResponse represents that the response was successfully sent.
sendResponse
close:480
work: 362
close362
work: 362
errno:9 362
work: 227
close227
work: 227
errno:9 227
work: 227
errno:9 227
work: 227
errno:9 227
work: 227
errno:9 227
work: 227
errno:9 227
work: 227
errno:9 227
work: 227
errno:9 227
work: 227
errno:9 227
work: 227
errno:9 227
work: 360
close360
work: 147
close147
```

This is the normal output.But I can't understand why there are so many outputs of the same connfd. Is it because multiple threads use the same connfd?

```
sendResponse
close:480
work: 480

sendResponse
close:480
work: 480
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? If you say "It seems that all threads are using the same connfd.", you can just check that with the debugger but that also should not be a guess? I mean you wrote the code.

Comment: I tried single-step debugging. They used the same connfd at the same time. Next, I will go to the new connfd. The last recv() always fails. It will set errno to 9. This is why I suspect that EPOLLONESHOT does not work in my program. It looks like multiple threads use one connfd.

Comment: It might be more interesting to see `Worker::init`, I actually suspect the error rather there. Actually you should post the `Worker` class itself, too, and maybe you even can remove some code that doesn't contribute to the problem (-> [mre]!).

Comment: Usually the server closes sockets only for specific reasons, e.g. like a specific time of inactivity of the client. If on any side the task actually has completed successfully it might close the socket, too, though I personally would implement some kind of *'I'm going to close'* message to allow *both* sides closing their sockets gracefully without having to rely on reading/writing failing – which allows to use the latter to identify unwanted connection losses.

Comment: Worker:: init simply assigns epollfd and confd to itself. I will add code related to it immediately.

Comment: I added some output information, but I didn't find the problem.

Comment: Why are you closing the socket right after re-registering it for another round?

Comment: Also bear in mind that EAGAIN means you are in the middle of something and you need to save the worker state and return to the same state to continue after tge socket is ready again. IOW you need to implement poor man's coroutines. Totally not worth it. Just check for EAGAIN in the read loop and continue looping.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, if you cancel the registration, it can complete the task. But if I don't close connfd in that location, it can't complete the task (whether registered or not).

Comment: Let's try again. You have a choice. (1) You can avoid delaying the task by NOT returning from Worker::work on EAGAIN, and continuing to loop instead. (2) You can return from Worker::work and delay the task. Now in order to resume the task, you need to save the state before leaving and restore it when the socket is ready again and you return to serve it, i.e. implement Worker::work as a *coroutine*. And you cannot `close` because that would interrupt the session in the middle. Suppose the client wants to write 2 lines, and you close the connection after the first one, what should the client do?

Comment: I think I should understand what you mean, so in fact, my EAGAIN judgment only reads the data once, right? That is to say, if I close it here and the client wants to send information again, it has to contact my listening socket again, right?

Comment: The client will get a connection closed error in the middle of its transmission, which it should interpret as an error. It may try again or just bail out.